# TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [2] of <class 'str'>

Tags: python-3.x, csv

**I am trying to execute customer allocation process using python code -**

```
import time
start = time.time()
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Cust_Data_April17.txt")
lkp=pd.read_csv("lookup_April17.csv")
df=df.sort_values(by=['alloc_cnt','alloc_id','RANKING'])
df1=df.drop_duplicates(['alloc_cnt','alloc_id','cust_id'], keep='first')
df1['alloc_id']=df1['alloc_id'].str.strip()
df4=pd.DataFrame([])
for i in range(lkp.shape[0]):
df2=df1[(lkp['alloc_cnt'][i]==df1['alloc_cnt'])&(lkp['alloc_id'][i]==df1['alloc_id'])]
    df3=df2[0:lkp['act_pct'][i]]
    df4=df4.append(df3,ignore_index=True)
df4.to_csv('Customer_Output.csv',index=False)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with this program?